# Jquery - Hide modal y controlar handler del evento click en input button

Tags: jquery, modal, eventos

tengo un problema al cerrar una ventana modal. En ella hay situado un input button el cual por jquery realizo una acción de consulta a una base de datos. Aquí os pongo parte del código que utilizo:

```
      // Show Detail Image
      $('.image-library').click(function() {

                // En este nivel abro la ventana modal con una serie de campos que consulto a la base de datos.

                // Activo el evento click si previamente se ha desactivado por cerrar la ventana modal.

                $('#btnApplyShowImage').bind('click'); 

                $('#btnApplyShowImage').click(function(event){

                        // Realizo una serie de acciones en la base de datos mediante una función json
                })
      })
```

El problema es que si cierro la ventana y la vuelvo abrir para posteriormente utilizar el input button, éste se ejecuta dos veces. Por lo que he leído resulta que al cargar el modal jquery ya lanza el controlador click del primer input button aún sin haberlo clicado. Al hacerlo el segundo también recoge el primero.

Disculpar seguramente no me haya explicado del todo bien.

La única solución que he encontrado es al cerrar la ventana modal utilizar la siguiente función para desactivar el evento click previamente cargado en el input button:

```
$('#showImage').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

         $('#btnApplyShowImage').unbind('click');

})
```

Lógicamente cuando cargo el modal activo el evento click:

```
$('#btnApplyShowImage').bind('click');
```

Mi duda es que no estoy seguro si es el planteamiento correcto o hay otra forma de anular este evento pre-cargado en memoria.

Gracias.

Comment: En donde tienes el codigo del `click` del boton `btnApplyShowImage`?

Comment: Una vez me paso algo similar, verifica que solo tienes importada la libreria de JQuery una sola vez, y no solo en el documento HTML actual, tambien en documentos HTML padres

Comment: Hola he modificado el post si te fijas he puesto el selector por #id en el evento click que corresponde a un input button. El código interno es una llamada json con una serie de acciones a la base de datos.

Comment: Hola. El documento sólo importa jquery una sola vez en la cabecera. No sé bien bien a que te refieres con documentos html padre pero te puedo decir que cada documento html carga la librería jquery pero no utilizo plantilla ni nada por estilo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cada vez que abres el modal asignas el handler `click` al boton.  Como ya te diste cuenta la solucion es deshabilitar el handler, pero una mejor practica es usar `on()` y `off()`.  De esta forma no necesitas una funcion diferente.  Quedaria asi:

```
$('#btnApplyShowImage').off('click');
$('#btnApplyShowImage').on('click', function(event){

    // Realizo una serie de acciones en la base de datos mediante una función json
});
```

Comment: Eso es sí. Gracias por la respuesta. No acabo de entender un detalle: la primera fila que me indicas desactiva el handler pero la segunda lo activa. Si lanzo el modal parece como que siempre la active puesto que esta posterior al desactivar o es que el activar queda como en stand by?

Comment: Correcto, cuando sales del modal el handler esta activado, pero cuando vuelves a entrar lo desactivas y vuelves a activar.

Comment: Entonces entiendo que es una buena práctica utilizar el evento off y on en cualquier evento que se lance dentro de un modal para ahorrar resultados indeseados. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)